# On use of any method

Tags: pandas, any

a code from Kaggle, which is said to remove outliners:

```
outliers_mask = (ft.abs() > ft.abs().quantile(outl_thresh)).any(axis=1)
```

Would not Any return a boolean item? either a an item being in a list or not?
So what the code says is, save in the mask all absolute values in Ft which are above the quantile (introduced by another variable)? What does the Any stand for? what for? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first part return DataFrame filled by boolean `True` or/and `False`:

```
(ft.abs() > ft.abs().quantile(outl_thresh))
```

so is added [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test if at least one `True` per rows to boolean `Series`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[False, False, True],
                   'b':[False, True, True],
                   'c':[False, False, True]})
                        
print (df)
       a      b      c
0  False  False  False
1  False   True  False
2   True   True   True

print (df.any(axis=1))
0    False <- no True per rows
1     True <- one True per rows
2     True <- three Trues per rows
dtype: bool
```

Similar method for test if all values are `True`s is [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
print (df.all(axis=1))
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Reason is for filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) is necessary boolean Series, not boolean DataFrame.

Another sample data:

```
np.random.seed(2021) 

ft = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(10, 5))).sub(20)
print (ft)
    0   1   2   3   4
0  65  37 -20  74  66
1  24  42  71   9   1
2  73   4  -8  50  50
3  13 -13 -19  77   6
4  46  28  79  43  29
5  -4  30  34  32  73
6 -15  29  18  -6  51
7  65  50  21   1   5
8 -10  16  -1  37  62
9  70  -5  20  56  33

outl_thresh = 0.95

print (ft.abs().quantile(outl_thresh))
0    71.65
1    46.40
2    75.40
3    75.65
4    69.85
Name: 0.95, dtype: float64
```

---

```
print((ft.abs() > ft.abs().quantile(outl_thresh)))
       0      1      2      3      4
0  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False
2   True  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False   True  False
4  False  False   True  False  False
5  False  False  False  False   True
6  False  False  False  False  False
7  False   True  False  False  False
8  False  False  False  False  False
9  False  False  False  False  False

outliers_mask = (ft.abs() > ft.abs().quantile(outl_thresh)).any(axis=1)
print (outliers_mask)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7     True
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

---

```
df1 = ft[outliers_mask]
print (df1)
    0   1   2   3   4
2  73   4  -8  50  50
3  13 -13 -19  77   6
4  46  28  79  43  29
5  -4  30  34  32  73
7  65  50  21   1   5
    0   1   2   3   4
    
df2 = ft[~outliers_mask]
print (df2)
    0   1   2   3   4
0  65  37 -20  74  66
1  24  42  71   9   1
6 -15  29  18  -6  51
8 -10  16  -1  37  62
9  70  -5  20  56  33
```